# How to go to next page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[Screenshot of Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRNzh.png)

```
link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("paginator-btn paginator-btn-next")
link.click()
```

I've tried this method but its not working

Answer (score 0):

class name do not work with spaces in selenium,

try this instead (with **css selector**):

```
link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".paginator-btn.paginator-btn-next")
link.click()
```

or using xpath:

```
//span[text()='Next Page']/..
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with below xpath, and it worked.

`"//div[@class='paginator']/button"`